# Django: Get one-day activity of object of Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

Above is my feed model

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    user  = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, verbose_name=_("user"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.IntegerField(_("Likes"),default=0)
    views = models.IntegerField(_("Views"),default=0)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My question is the likes and views of this feed(model) will increase day by day, so if I want to know how likes or views got added today. How can I get that?

For example, on first day feed gets 10 views, on second day it got 30 so the total of 40 views and on third day(present day) the total got to 70, the increase is 30, like this how can I get increase in views is 30 today in Django?

Comment: You can aggregate on the current day, with `Feed.objects.filter(date_created__date=date.today()).aggregate(Sum('likes'))` (with `from datetime import date` and `from django.db.models import Sum`).

Comment: It will give me object created today.

Comment: I want **increase** in likes today of  previously created object.